# How to find center of gravity of a circle with a hollow circle in it?

Tags: classical-mechanics

How do i find the center of gravity of this figure?

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/68z2R.png

How do i find the center of gravity of this figure?
M = 14a
N= 6a. I know I have to find the area of both circles then big one - small one.(that's what we did In class),but didn't understand what to do after.
thanks in advance :)

Comment: You have to treat the missing circle as negative mass. Them you may use the standard centre of mass coordinate formula to solve.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way : take the center of gravity of the first disk weighted by its positive area $\pi 49 a^2$ and  the second one weighted by its negative weight $-\pi 9 a^2$, all being divided by the algebraic sum $\pi 49 a^2-\pi 9 a^2=\pi 40 a^2$.